# create polylines with different colors in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have one function which creates poly line & adds that polyline to map

```
        function makeRoute(e)
    {
        if(pointsSelection.length > 0)
        {
            pointsSelection.push(e.target.getLatLng());
            var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointsSelection, {
            color: 'blue',
            weight: 5,
            smoothFactor: 1
            });

            firstpolyline.addTo(map);

            pointsArrayCollection.push(pointsSelection);
            polyArrayCollection.push(firstpolyline);

            selection = [];
            pointsSelection = [];
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please select more than one point");
        }
    }
```

my problem is that It adds line with same color every time.

I want to add poly lines with different colors every time.

So how can I change color of polyline dynamically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For changing color I am using random color generator function.

Use get_random_color() in place of 'blue':

```
function get_random_color() 
{
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) 
    {
       color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
return color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [viabhav shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1498159/vaibhav-shah)'s answer (which is correct), your total solution would be:

```
function makeRoute(e) {

    if(pointsSelection.length > 0) {
        pointsSelection.push(e.target.getLatLng());
        var firstpolyline = new L.Polyline(pointsSelection, {
        color: get_random_color(),
        weight: 5,
        smoothFactor: 1
        });

        firstpolyline.addTo(map);

        pointsArrayCollection.push(pointsSelection);
        polyArrayCollection.push(firstpolyline);

        selection = [];
        pointsSelection = [];

    } else {
        alert("Please select more than one point");
    }

    // Function to create a random color
    function get_random_color() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
            color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
        } 
        return color;
    }
}
```

Vaibhav Shah has the correct answer, so vote for his solution.